# create 2D dictionary from json file to get counts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json object that looks like this and I have read this into a variable called myData

```
{
{
    issue : 'A1',
    pdate : '2021-05-21'
    type : 'small'
},
{
    issue : 'A2',
    pdate : '2021-05-21'
    type : 'med'
},
{
    issue : 'A4',
    pdate : '2021-05-21'
    type : 'large'
},
{
    issue : 'A22',
    pdate : '2021-06-21'
    type : 'small'
},
{
    issue : 'A222',
    pdate : '2021-06-21'
    type : 'small'
},
{
    issue : 'A422',
    pdate : '2021-06-21'
    type : 'small'
}
}
```

I want to get how many items of each time exist on a given day.
My current code is something like this

```
var dict = {};
myData.map((elem) => {
  var xkey = elem.pdate;
  dict[xkey] = xkey in dict ? dict[xkey] + 1 : 1;
});
```

this given me a dict like this

```
2021-05-21 : 3,
2021-06-21 : 2
```

Now I want to convert this into a dictionary or a 2D array so I can know how many diff type of items are present on a given day.

```
{ 
'2021-05-21' : {'small':1,'med':1,'large':1},
'2021-06-21' : {'small' : 2}
}
```

Please can someone help me write this. I have tried diff combinations of if conditions to make this work but I am unable to get this. Also this doesn't have to be a dictionary, either an array or a dict, as long as I am able to iterate over it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this works:

```
const test = [{
    issue : 'A1',
    pdate : '2021-05-21',
    type : 'small'
},
{
    issue : 'A2',
    pdate : '2021-05-21',
    type : 'med'
},
{
    issue : 'A4',
    pdate : '2021-05-21',
    type : 'large'
},
{
    issue : 'A22',
    pdate : '2021-06-21',
    type : 'small'
},
{
    issue : 'A222',
    pdate : '2021-06-21',
    type : 'small'
},
{
    issue : 'A422',
    pdate : '2021-06-21',
    type : 'small'
}]

const output = {};

test.forEach((obj) => {
  if (!output[obj.pdate]) {
    output[obj.pdate] = {};
  }
  if (!output[obj.pdate][obj.type]) {
    output[obj.pdate][obj.type] = 0;
  }
  output[obj.pdate][obj.type] += 1;
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks a lot Swaraj.